# Divide array into subarrays whose sum is even

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have an array of $N$ integers e.g $\{1 , 2 , 2, 3\}$

How many ways can I divide this array into non-overlapping subarrays , whose individual sum is even?

e.g in case of above :

$\{2,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$

$\{2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$

$\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{2\}$

Comment: You want an exact number? Or you are fine with a recursive approach. Looks like programming challenge.

Comment: I was looking for the recursive approach. A bare psueudo code or logic will suffice. Got kinda stuck over this.